# How to force an Async Context Manager to Exit

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-trio, structured-concurrency

I've been getting into Structured Concurrency recently and this is a pattern that keeps cropping up:

It's nice to use async context managers to access resource - say a some websocket. That's all great if the websocket stays open, but what about if it closes? well we expect our context to be forcefully exited - normally through an exception.

How can I write and implement a context manager that exhibits this behaviour? How can I throw an exception 'into' the calling codes open context? How can I forcefully exit a context?

Here's a simple setup, just for argument's sake:

```py
# Let's pretend I'm implementing this:
class SomeServiceContextManager:
    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.service.connect(self.connection_state_callback)
        return self.service

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        self.service.disconnect()
        return False

    def connection_state_callback(self, state):
        if state == "connection lost":
            print("WHAT DO I DO HERE? how do I inform my consumer and force the exit of their context manager?")

class Consumer:
    async def send_stuff(self):
        try:
            async with SomeServiceContextManager(self.service) as connected_service:
                while True:
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    connected_service.send("hello")
        except ConnectionLostException: #<< how do I implement this from the ContextManager?
            print("Oh no my connection was lost!!")
```

How is this generally handled? It seems to be something I've run up into a couple of times when writing ContextManagers!

Here's a slightly more interesting example (hopefully) to demonstrate how things get a bit messy - say you are receiving through an async loop but want to close your connection if something downstream disconnects:

```py
# Let's pretend I'm implementing this:
class SomeServiceContextManager:
    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.service.connect(self.connection_state_callback)
        return self.service

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        self.service.disconnect()
        return False

    def connection_state_callback(self, state):
        if state == "connection lost":
            print("WHAT DO I DO HERE? how do I inform my consumer and force the exit of their context manager?")

class Consumer:
    async def translate_stuff_stuff(self):
        async with SomeOtherServiceContextManager(self.otherservice) as connected_other_service:
            try:
                async with SomeServiceContextManager(self.service) as connected_service:
                    for message in connected_other_service.messages():
                        connected_service.send("message received: " + message.text)
            except ConnectionLostException: #<< how do I implement this from the ContextManager?
                print("Oh no my connection was lost - I'll also drop out of the other service connection!!")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. If the `with` block raises an exception, `__aexit__` will be called. So maybe put your code there?

Comment: Oh I think I understand. Your question is how you can achieve that an exception will be raised in the `with` block in the first place. In the simplest case `connected_service.send` will raise it.

Comment: Thanks - that's sadly not quite what I want to achieve - I'd like a more immediate disconnect that 'next time you try and send'

Comment: An immediate exception is a bad idea - you have no idea what you might be interrupting. That kind of thing leads to nasty data structure corruption and debugging nightmares. For example, Java's `Thread::stop` is deprecated, for removal, because throwing a `ThreadDeath` into unknown code is inherently, unfixably unsafe.

Comment: The situation is *slightly* safer with coroutines than threads, if "immediately" is limited by cooperative multitasking and the consumer can only be interrupted when it suspends, but you'd still be relying on a lot of unknown code to be safe in the face of arbitrary exceptions at arbitrary suspend points. That includes not just the consumer's own code, but also everything it `await`s, and everything that code `await`s, and so on.

Comment: Your websocket library likely has a function like `async def drain(self)`. Your code should make sure to await this function periodically. Drain waits for all messages to finish sending and raise an error if they cannot be sent. It will help you to stop publishing data faster than you can send, and in the event that the connection is lost it will raise an exception. Async code is cooperative by design. It is the senders responsibility to check it can still send.

Comment: Don't anchor too much on the web socket thing - that's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get started, let's replace manual `__aenter__()` and `__aexit__()` implementations with [`contextlib.asynccontextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager). This takes care of handling exceptions properly and is especially useful when you have nested context managers, as we're going to have in this answer. Here's your snippet rewritten in this way.

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

class SomeServiceConnection:
    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service

    async def _connect(self, connection_state_callback):
        await self.service.connect(connection_state_callback)

    async def _disconnect(self):
        self.service.disconnect()

@asynccontextmanager
async def get_service_connection(service):
    connection = SomeServiceConnection(service)
    await connection._connect(
        ...  # to be done
    )
    try:
        yield connection
    finally:
        await connection._disconnect()
```

OK, with that out of the way: The core of the answer here is that, if you want to stop running tasks in response to some event, then use a cancel scope.

```py
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_service_connection(service):
    connection = SomeServiceConnection(service)
    with trio.CancelScope() as cancel_scope:
        await connection._connect(cancel_scope.cancel)
        try:
            yield connection
        finally:
            await connection._disconnect()
            if cancel_scope.called:
                raise RuntimeError("connection lost")
```

But wait... what if some other exception (or exceptions!) were thrown at roughly the same time that the connection was closed? That would be lost when you raise your own exception. This is handily dealt with by using a nursery instead. This has its own cancel scope doing the cancellation work, but it also deals with creating `ExceptionGroup` objects (formerly known as `MultiError`s). Now your callback just needs to raise an exception inside the nursery. As a bonus, there is a good chance you needed to run a background task to make the callback happen anyway. (If not, e.g., your callback is called from another thread via a Trio token, then use a `trio.Event` as another answer suggested, and await it from within the nursery.)

```py
async def check_connection(connection):
    await connection.wait_disconnected()
    raise RuntimeError("connection lost")

@asynccontextmanager
async def get_service_connection(service):
    connection = SomeServiceConnection(service)
    await connection._connect()
    try:
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            nursery.start_soon(check_connection)
            yield connection
            nursery.cancel_scope.cancel()
    finally:
        await connection._disconnect()
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! This is great! Is there an equivalent in asyncio without having to use Trio?

Comment: @Sam Yes, you can use an [AnyIO `TaskGroup`](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html). That library has a unified interface to asyncio and Trio. If you're using Trio, `anyio.TaskGroup` is just an alias for `trio.Nursery`, but on `asyncio` it's a reimplementation.

Comment: Oh interesting. Is asyncio TaskGroup not up to the job? Or I guess are you talking for older versions of python. There's also aiotools.TaskGroup

Comment: Oh interesting. Is asyncio TaskGroup not up to the job? Or I guess are you talking for older versions of python. There's also aiotools.TaskGroup

Comment: @Sam To be honest I forgot about `asyncio.TaskGroup`! It will probably do but make sure you understand its different cancellation semantics. They are too complex to describe in a comment so I posted a separate question / answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78060510/what-is-the-difference-between-anyio-taskgroup-and-asyncio-taskgroup/78060511#78060511

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `asyncio.Event` to communicate the disconnect from `SomeServiceContextManager` to `Consumer`.

Then instead of waiting for 1 second in each iteration of the loop by using `asyncio.sleep`, you wait for the disconnect event *for up to 1 second* and if it does not occur you continue as before. This can be achieved e.g. by using [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for).

```
class SomeServiceContextManager:
    def __init__(self, service):
        # … as before
        self._disconnect = asyncio.Event()  # added

    async def __aenter__(self):
        # in case the context manager is reusable and the event was set before
        self._disconnect.clear()  # added
        # … as before

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        # … as before

    def connection_state_callback(self, state):
        if state == "connection lost":
            self._disconnect.set()  # new

    async def wait_for_disconnect(self, timeout):  # added
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self._disconnect.wait(), timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:  # just TimeoutError in newer Python versions
            pass  # OK, no disconnect within timeout
        else:
            raise ConnectionLostException

class Consumer:
    async def send_stuff(self):
        try:
            async with SomeServiceContextManager(self.service) as connected_service:
                while True:
                    # changed
                    await connected_service.wait_for_disconnect(timeout=1.0)
                    connected_service.send("hello")
        except ConnectionLostException:
            print("Oh no my connection was lost!!")
```

Comment: I like this a little, but the consumer becomes a little too aware of the internals. What if the consumer is waiting for something else, like a message from some other async generator? Now we have to wait on two things

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this in the first place? Some sort of `ConnectionLost` exception will be raised by the current and/or next `read` or `write` call on the connection. (Alternately you'll get an empty reply, which you should use to raise an `EOFError`.)

There is no need for state-change callbacks. IMHO they're a design mistake.
In fact, most of asyncio's connection handling is a mess, for historic reasons; you should consider using the `anyio` wrapper, which incidentally does the `EOFError` thing for you. Additional advantage: your code will run with Trio as well.

Comment: There are many reasons. You may want to use disconnecting to update displays or enable other backup code

Comment: The fact remains that the disconnect will raise an exception when reading or writing. Catch and handle that exception and you're set.

If you think "but what if I'm doing neither", well, if no task accesses the connection then there's no task that notices and runs the callback.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the EOF piece? I don't see where the 'empty reply' translates toe EOFError in anyio.

Actually the structure of the code reads nicely if you're saying 'im going to open a connection to a server to receive messages and a connection to a piece of hardware. Whenever the server sends a message I will act on the hardware. BUT if server disconnects, I want to relinquish the hardware. I don't want to implement a keep-alive just for that - that's the point of a websocket - the connection itself is async

Comment: anyio's `receive` method does the "if the result is empty, raise `EOFError`" bit for you.