# What is the difference between anyio.TaskGroup and asyncio.TaskGroup?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-trio, python-anyio

The [AnyIO library](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is designed to give a unified interface between asyncio and [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It has a [`TaskGroup` class](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html) mimicking the Trio `Nursery` class. Indeed, if using Trio as the backend, it is just an alias for `trio.Nursery`; but, if using asyncio as the backend, it is a complete reimplementation.

But recent versions of Python (3.11 onwards) provide their own [`asyncio.Taskgroup` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups).

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5):

The AnyIO documentation [lists a few differences between the two](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#differences-with-asyncio-taskgroup). But it does not include the really big one: **level-based cancellation** vs **edge-based cancellation**.

AnyIO task groups (and Trio nurseries) use **level-based cancellation**. That means that, once the task group is cancelled (either manually by calling [`tg.cancel_scope.cancel()`](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#anyio.CancelScope.cancel) or implicitly because a task within has raised an exception), all further calls within that task group will throw a cancellation exception (unless [shielded](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cancellation.html#shielding)) which will be caught by the task group. Here is an example:

```
import anyio

async def cancel_soon():
    print("cancel_soon starting")
    await anyio.sleep(0.5)
    raise RuntimeError

async def wait_and_print(i):
    print(f"Wait {i} starting")
    try:
        await anyio.sleep(1)
        print(f"Wait {i} done")
    except BaseException as e:
        print(f"Wait {i} except: {e!r}")
        raise

async def double_wait():
    try:
        await wait_and_print(1)
    finally:
        await wait_and_print(2)

async def anyio_group_test():
    try:
        async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
            tg.start_soon(double_wait)
            tg.start_soon(cancel_soon)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"test caught: {e!r}")

anyio.run(anyio_group_test)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Wait 1 starting
cancel_soon starting
Wait 1 except: CancelledError('Cancelled by cancel scope 1dea0d2a2d0')
Wait 2 starting
Wait 2 except: CancelledError('Cancelled by cancel scope 1dea0d2a2d0')
test caught: ExceptionGroup('unhandled errors in a TaskGroup', [RuntimeError()])
```

Notice how the same task in the group got a cancellation exception twice, because after the first one was dispatched we tried to await something else.

In contrast, asyncio task groups use **edge-based cancellation**. This means that any currently active tasks (which must all be sitting in an `await`) will receive a cancellation exception, but then any future calls will continue as usual. Consider this example (reusing the utility functions from the snippet before):

```py
import asyncio

async def asyncio_group_test():
    try:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            tg.create_task(double_wait())
            tg.create_task(cancel_soon())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"test caught: {e!r}")

asyncio.run(asyncio_group_test())
```

This will produce output like this:

```
Wait 1 starting
cancel_soon starting
Wait 1 except: CancelledError()
Wait 2 starting
Wait 2 done
test caught: ExceptionGroup('unhandled errors in a TaskGroup', [RuntimeError()])
```

Note how, in the `finally:` block in `double_wait()`, the second sleep was allowed to run to completion rather than re-raising the cancellation exception.

(By the way, this explain the final entry in the list of differences linked to at the strat of the answer: asyncio does not allow tasks to be started in a task group that has been cancelled. That's because there's no way that this task would ever "find out" about the cancellation. In contrast, anyio does allow tasks to be started in a task group that has been cancelled, because it will still receive a cancellation exception as soon as it gets to its first (non-shielded) await.)

Edge-based cancellation is potentially a lot more fragile because if some utility function within a task accidentally suppresses a cancellation exception then the rest of the task will continue indefinitely, unaware that it is operating in a context that ought to be cancelled.

---

Here is another (related) difference between them. AnyIO task groups (and Trio nurseries) will **immediately recursively cancel all tasks within them**. In asyncio task groups, this will *eventually* happen (so long as nothing suppresses cancellation exceptions) but tasks within nested task groups will only be cancelled when that inner task group comes to a close.

That's all a bit abstract but it's clear from an example. Consider this snippet:

```
async def example():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as outer_tg:
        outer_tg.create_task(foo(1))
        outer_tg.create_task(foo(2))
        outer_tg.create_task(cancel_soon())
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as inner_tg:
            inner_tg.create_task(foo(3))
            inner_tg.create_task(foo(4))
            await foo(5)
```

It doesn't matter exactly what `foo()` is, but imagine that it takes a while to run and also takes a while to cancel (because it catches `asyncio.CancelledError`, sleeps a bit, and then re-raises it). So, when `cancel_soon()` raises an exception, all 5 calls to `foo()` are still running.

- **In asyncio, when `outer_tg` gets the exception, it will initially only cancel `foo(1)`, `foo(2)` and `foo(5)`**. Only when `foo(5)` completes (e.g. by allowing `asyncio.CancelledError` to escape) and `inner_tg` gets to the end of its block does it cancel `foo(3)` and `foo(4)`. If `foo(5)` suppresses the cancellation exception then they won't be cancelled at all.
- **In the AnyIO and Trio versions of this code, when `outer_tg` gets the exception, all the calls to `foo()` are cancelled immediately**.

Comment: asyncio doesn't even have a way to cancel a taskgroup because it doesn't have cancel scopes as a separate concept. Instead, it cancels the task (and its subtasks of course). No scopes also means that shielding some code against outside cancellation (e.g. clean up code that needs to do some async work) is difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: That is true. It matches what I said but you've just used a slightly different (technically more accurate) definition of "cancellation". I've now added an extra difference which is also a consequence of what you wrote